# Improvements NativeScript App

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've tested my nativescript app as here - https://www.nativescript.org/blog/deep-dive-into-nativescript-3.1-performance-improvements
My result is this - the start of the program and user login takes 18 seconds. Is that okay?
Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

My production build takes roughly 2 seconds to start up. Development builds may take 5-8 secs.

How long it takes purely depends on how much stuffs you are loading at startup, so you may want follow the guidelines and see where exactly it's taking time.

Comment: Thank for you answer.